# Hide input image URL

Tags: html, css

Am using the following code to change look of input file type, i just changed input select type as image   and my problem is **How can i hide input image URL**
**HTML**

```
<form action="for.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple id="files" class="hidden"/>
        <input type="submit" id="sub"/>
    </form>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type="file"] {
            border: 1px gray dashed;
            background:no-repeat center gainsboro;
            text-indent: -9999em;
            line-height:3000;
            width: 128px;
            height: 128px;
        }
```

[image]

**How do i hide image name after selected**

Comment: You're trying to hide an `<input type="image" />` element?

Comment: can help me how to hide URL of image for the above code

Comment: I don't understand your question, so I can't help you. I think you should ask a colleague, or friend, that's more fluent in English to help you translate, and better-explain, your question. As it is it's extremely difficult to understand.

Comment: when i choose image in input box , image url is displayed is there any way to hide to image name

Comment: @DavidThomas check my question how do i hide image name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just skip above code and use following code

**HTML**

```
<form action="for.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="inputWrapper">
            <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple id="files" class="hidden fileInput"/>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" id="sub">
    </form>
```

**CSS**

```
.inputWrapper {
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: #DDF;
            border: 1px gray dashed;
            background: url('file_add.png') no-repeat center gainsboro;
            text-indent: -9999em;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }

        .fileInput {
            cursor: pointer;
            height: 100%;
            position:absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            font-size:50px;
        }
        .hidden {
            opacity: 0;
            -moz-opacity: 0;
            filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0)
        }
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

Comment: how can i hide with using only css